# URL encoded space does not work in Content-Disposition header in IE11 using filename*?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, servlets, http-headers, specifications

I'm trying to deliver a file to the browser that can have non-ASCII characters in the file name and I've been playing around with using the `Content-Disposition` header to tell the browser about the desired file name to use when the user wants to save the file.

I've looked at [RFC 6266](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266) where I saw the use of `filename*`.
So, as a test, I set the following header in a Java servlet (where `resp` is a `HttpServletResponse`):

```
resp.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=test.png; filename*=utf-8''test%20x.png");
```

It seems that all "modern" browsers understand this now and support `filename*` and also prefer it over the value set for `filename`. I've tried it with Arabic characters and they worked fine in the latest Chrome and Firefox versions and in IE11. But: unlike the other browsers IE does not seem to understand the `%20` here. When I try to save the file it has the file name as `test%20x.png` instead of `test x.png`.

Has anyone encountered this before? Is it an IE bug? And if so, are there workarounds? (I could just replace the space with an underscore but maybe I don't have to.)

Maybe I'm doing something wrong with the encoding or maybe it's to do with the Java Servlet environment. (I doubt it but I tagged the question as a Java Servlet one anyway in case it is.)
I can provide more details about how the file is delivered by the servlet if necessary but maybe someone has seen this with IE in a different environment as well.

Comment: this looks relevant to your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http

Comment: @Roman: Yeah, I looked at that before but it didn't help. :-/
Thanks anyway!